# Reading a text file in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm in the middle of writing a bot I have most of it done but I've hit a wall.

I have a text file and i want the bot to search the file to see if a word is on there, if it is then reply yes they are, if they are not reply no they are not

I want it to work like this

```
!Platoon XXX (XXX= word from file)
```

Bot replies

```
Yes they are in platoon
```

or

```
No they are not in platoon
```

So far I have

```
@client.command()
async def Platoon(ctx):
         await ctx.send('Checking File please stand by.')
         f = open("Platoon.txt", "r")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `re` library to find word in each line.

```py
import re



@client.command()
async def Platoon(ctx, *, word: str):
    await ctx.send('Checking File please stand by.')
    with open("Platoon.txt", "r") as f:
        searching = re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(word), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
        line = True
        while line:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if searching(line):
                await ctx.send("Yes they are in platoon")
                return
    await ctx.send("No they are not in platoon")
```

Comment: Thanks so much this was just what i needed, for the life of me everything i tried i was hitting a brick wall. I have much more to learn. When run if a word is split into 2 it will come back with a Yes when it should be No. I'll try figure it out Thanks again.